# How to look for required methods in a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, documentation, objective-c-protocol

This is what I do. While looking up an apple documentation of protocol in Chrome or Xcode, I Cmd-F searching for "required". If result is zero, I conclude that all methods in that protocol are optional.

Am I doing it right? Or is there any "formal" way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most authoritative answer to the "optional" vs "required" question would come directly from the header that implements the protocol in question.

If you've already got an object marked as implementing the protocol, you can right-click->Jump to Definition in XCode. Once you're at the definition, anything before the `@optional` keyword is required, and anything after it is optional (unless there's another `@required` later, but that's rare).

That said, in my experience, the Apple Developer Documentation has always been quite reliable for me in adding "*required method*" after any methods that the protocol does, in fact, require.

Comment: I agree that looking up in the header file of the protocol is the ultimate authoritative way. But what if I didn't implement the protocol in my project, I just want to know the answer quickly. Is the Cmd-F way all right? Plus, how to jump to the related header file in apple documentation?

Comment: Yeah--Cmd-F is fine almost all of the time.